# Error while installing the windows service using installutil command?

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I Will Explain what i am exactly doing.

**STEP 1:**

I Have taken the one class library file in which i have added the WCF service. In this service i am peforming operations.

**STEP 2:**

I have added the windows service in the same solution. In this service i have hosted the WCF service and debug it.

So it is working fine.

**STEP 3:**

Then I had created the set up of that files using installshied(basic msi project) and i install it. It is working fine.

But I am trying to install it using InstallUtil.exe it is giving error.

> > Error Message:-
> >     Installing assembly 'C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.exe'.
> >     Affected parameters are:
> >        i = 
> >        logtoconsole = 
> >        logfile = C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.InstallLog
> >        assemblypath = C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.exe
> >        name = HostCompression
> >     Installing service HostCompression...
> >     Service HostCompression has been successfully installed.
> >     Creating EventLog source HostCompression in log Application...
> >     An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.
> >     System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service HostCompression on computer '.'.
> >     The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: 
> >     The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
> >     Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.exe'.
> >     Affected parameters are:
> >        i = 
> >        logtoconsole = 
> >        logfile = C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.InstallLog
> >        assemblypath = C:\Users\Dattaprasad\Desktop\TestAllBrowswer\WindowsService1.exe
> >        name = HostCompression
> >     Restoring event log to previous state for source HostCompression.
> >     Service HostCompression is being removed from the system...
> >     Service HostCompression was successfully removed from the system.

What I have tried:

Service1.cs file:-

```
    ServiceHost m_serviceHost;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (m_serviceHost != null) m_serviceHost.Close();

        //string strAdrHTTP = "http://localhost:9100/CompressService/";
        string strAdrTCP = "net.tcp://localhost:9200/CompressService";
        string strAdrWebHttp = "http://localhost:9100/CompressService";

        Uri[] adrbase = { 
                            //new Uri(strAdrHTTP),
                            new Uri(strAdrTCP), 
                            new Uri(strAdrWebHttp) 
                        };
        m_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestAllBrowser.Test), adrbase);

        // ServiceDebugBehavior debug = m_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();


        ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        m_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

        //m_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior() { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });

        #region BasicHttpBinding
        #endregion

        #region NetTcpBinding

        NetTcpBinding tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
        tcpb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        tcpb.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        tcpb.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        tcpb.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        //tcpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        //tcpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        tcpb.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);
        tcpb.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);
        tcpb.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);

        m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TestAllBrowser.ITest), tcpb, strAdrTCP);
        m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");

        #endregion

        #region WebHttpBinding

        WebHttpBinding webb = new WebHttpBinding();
        webb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        webb.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        webb.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        webb.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        //webb.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        //webb.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        webb.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);
        webb.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);
        webb.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00);
        webb.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true;

        m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TestAllBrowser.ITest), webb, strAdrWebHttp).Behaviors.Add((IEndpointBehavior)new WebHttpBehavior());

        m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

        #endregion

        m_serviceHost.Open();

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (m_serviceHost != null)
            m_serviceHost.Close();
        m_serviceHost = null;
    }
```

ProjectInstaller.cs file:-

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    private IContainer components = (IContainer)null;
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;
    private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        this.process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.service = new ServiceInstaller();
        this.service.ServiceName = "HostCompression";
        this.service.DisplayName = "HostCompression";
        this.service.Description = "WCF Service Hosted";
        this.service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        this.Installers.Add((Installer)this.process);
        this.Installers.Add((Installer)this.service);
        this.service.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(this.serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall);
    }

    private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        new ServiceController("HostCompression").Start();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }
```

Comment: My advice would be to drop the windows installer stuff and just use topshelf. http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong. *An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service HostCompression on computer '.'. **The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.***